# Store array in jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am storing array in cookie through jQuery cookie plugin but each time I get it from cookie, it returns empty

I define array as:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[ 0 ] = "hello";
myArray[ 1 ] = "world";
```

Set it in cookie

```
$.cookie('cookie-array', myArray);
```

But getting this cookie and printing, prints empty string

```
console.log($.cookie('cookie-array'));
```

EDIT:
Arrays define in other questions are object arrays no like this array I mentioned here. Also I dont want to user JSON library.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at:
https://code.google.com/p/cookies/

to store an array

```
$.cookie('COOKIE_NAME', escape(myArray.join(',')), {expires:1234});
```

to get it back

```
cookie=unescape($.cookie('COOKIE_NAME'))
myArray=cookie.split(',')
```

Comment: it gives error while joining myArray. myArray.join(',')